# Android Google Map User location icon

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I'm trying to create an app that will track user's location and show him, in his field of view, some markers. Now the issue I'm having is, I am not sure if my way of doing this is correct. I have a special marker, that I customized, to show user's location no map. This user's marker should also have a special listener so that when the user taps on his icon, he will be presented with an option to add marker on his current location (I was thinking of doing some sort of Circle menu).

Is this correct way of doing it? In the GoogleMap documentation I didn't find anything that would resemble a special class for user's location. The only thing that came close was MyLocation() method. But when you turn this on it only puts a button on top of the screen and once the user taps it, it starts tracking his location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly check this repository on GitHub from Google it contains most of the map implementations all in source code, it is your best way around working with maps in Android. Download the source code and register your api key in the application, you can then compile an apk on your phone and see all the google map implementation.

https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples

[image]

Comment: Thanks I will check it out.